# Entity Framework - Model First, Many-to-Many Mapping

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4.1, ef-model-first

In a database I have two tables `User` and `Organization` as well as a bridging table `Users_Orgs`.

The `Users_Orgs` table has a composite key comprising of two columns `userId` and `organizationId`. When I use the designer to create an association it creates two principals for the referential constraint - `Users` and `Users_Orgs`. The problem is with the `Users_Orgs` constraint - it has a key comprising of both `organizationId` and `userId`. Since `organizationId` is not in the `User` table, it cannot be mapped and therefore won't compile.

[image: Users_Orgs table]
[image: Users_Orgs Constraints]

When clicking the 'Delete' button the dialog just closes and `organizationId` is just mapped to the primary key for the users table (which is not userId)

How can you do many to many mappings with composite keys on an existing database?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have bridging table in your model? It is not needed if you don't have additional properties in this table. Otherwise you should just model relation between `Users` and `Organizations` and correctly configure many-to-many multiplicity. EF will automatically create bridging table and mapping for this relation.

To solve your issue: Bridging table is dependent, not principal. Switch roles in the constraint and map `User.UserId` PK to `Users_Orgs.UserId` FK.

Comment: The bridging table is not my creation, it is from an existing database. I can't change the database as it is part of a CMS (Liferay) and could change with hotfixes and updates